# .net core - MVC webapp will not display my JSON Collection

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

So I'm working on a .net web app and I'm trying to display my order item when making get request with postman. Everything is working EXCEPT my collection property will not display. It just shows an empty array. I know that its not null but I can't seem to get the one Item inside the collection to display.

In this particular course, when the instructor runs his code, he actually get an error about having a "Self Referencing loop". He fixes this by adding some JSON options to the startup services that allow him to simply ignore the error. I am using a new version so I dont even have the particular options that he has. I do not get this error, instead Im having the issue of my json collection simply not displaying, even tho I know that its there.

Lastly I am getting these warnings but I don't think they are the issue.

```
No type was specified for the decimal column 'UnitPrice' on entity 
type 'OrderItem'. This will cause values to be silently truncated 
if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly 
specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the 
values using 'HasColumnType()'.
```

I run the following get request "http://localhost:7777/api/orders" and postman displays the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "orderDate": "2020-07-04T15:07:45.0980634",
    "orderNumber": "12345",
    "items": []
}
```

This is my Order object:

```cs
       public class Order
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
      }
```

This is my OrderController Get Method:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(repository);
                return Ok(repository.GetAllOrders());
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Failed to get orders: {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Failed to get orders");
            }
        }
```

My Repo method is here:

```cs
   public IEnumerable<Order> GetAllOrders()
        {
            
            return ctx.Orders
                .Include(o => o.Items)
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Product)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Order Item:

```
public class OrderItem
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show where you have defined the UnitPrice and how?

Comment: Yep just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly define the decimal for the property `UnitPrice`like this `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]` in the `OrderItem` class according to the table column defined in the database

Comment: I think your right. Do you know how that complete syntax would look?

Comment: [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks! I did that and it does resolve the error but still no luck get it to display. Is there a chance I would have to update the database still?

Comment: @MartyCarr so it has solved your original issue which you have asked in the question. Ask a different question or update the question with the latest observation

Comment: No sorry it resolves a "warning" not the original error.

Comment: So what's the issue now?

Comment: The object itself never actually gets created. The particular object that wont display in the json of the get request. I will link the github in case there's something wrong that I cant see

https://github.com/mcarr390/Dutch-Treat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740775/so-im-having-an-issue-creating-an-object-in-a-net-mvc-web-application-using-ef

Answer (score 0):

ctx.Products.Include(s=>s.Items).OrderBy(p => p.Title).ToList();